# Creating relationships between tables that where not specified in the given UML diagram

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-theory, relational-algebra, relational-calculus

Good evening!

I'm working on designing my very first actual database from the following UML class diagram (in French unfortunately):

[image: UML description of the database]

I'm at the point of creating the relational sketch of it which I created this way:

[image: RelationalScheme]

Yet, it creates some issues when trying to ask to the database *which are the clients that never ordered product number one?*

Indeed, I don't know how to do it in SQL as far as it seems that there is no relations between **Client**, **Commande** and **Produit**. It gived the following sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE Client (
IDClient INT NOT NULL,
AdresseClient VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL ,
NomContact VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
NumeroSIRET VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT cclient PRIMARY KEY (IDClient)
);

CREATE TABLE Produit (
IDProduit INT NOT NULL  ,
PrixVente INT NOT NULL ,
QuantiteEnStock INT NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAiNT cproduit PRIMARY KEY (IDProduit)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Commande (
IDNumeroCde INT NOT NULL  ,
Date DATE NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT ccommande PRIMARY KEY (IDNumeroCde)
);
```

In relational algebra and calculus it gives:

[image: Relational algebra and calculus]

The fact that I can't explain it in relational calculus let me think that I've done a mistake.

## Edit with the new tables

I read all the links you provided and therfore add some comments and changes on my tables, can you tell me if I'm right on my assumptions?

[image: The new relational scheme]

**But the last ones have the same primary key then. is it a problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML **class** diagrams do not include relations in a class' attributes list, so when creating database tables representing those classes, the database designer must identify and specify them, much like the software developer must create the pointers and lists to support the related objects.

In your diagram, `Commande` relates to `Client` but does not explicitly specify a `IDClient` attribute. When creating the `Commande` table, you must include this attribute along with a foreign key to `Client`.

You can find further information about this in [Database Design - UML/SQL](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=association.php):

> The UML representation of the Order class contains only its own descriptive attributes. The UML association tells which customer placed an order. In the database, we will need a different way to identify the customer; that will be part of the relation scheme (below).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I may be right but this was unexpected for me and my colleagues and I therefore started a bounty.

Comment: @Marine1 I've extended the answer somewhat and included sources for you to verify.

Comment: Okay, I'm okay with the answer. I leave the bounty open for a few more days if an even better answer poped out and I will award then, thanks!
Could you provide an example  to make it straight and clear?

Comment: I've just updated a new table using the reference you gived, can you tell me if my assumptions are right?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ziggy answer, if you want to make this diagram work, you need to edit it, for example you should create a third table called `cleint_order` and this table has primary key from `Client` table and `idproduct` from `product` table since one client may have one or more product and one product can be ordered from many customers.

useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de

Comment: That's what we did at the beginning, but I don't remember why did we deleted it. We have to this because it is a one to several relation, isn't it? Your link is useful.

Comment: I've just updated a new table using the link you gived, can you tell me if my assumptions are good?